# MySql query optimization approach

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am working on a dashboard in PHP MySql, where users will login and access the dashboard, 
user may have access to single section and single country or multiple sections and multiple countries.

i have made 3 predefined views and from the predefined views i am inserting into summary tables
and allowing the users to access the summary tables.

these are my predefined views

**unit_details**

```
          select 
      sections.section_id,
      countries.country_id,
      business_units.unit_id,
      sections.section_name,
      countries.country_name,
      cities.city_name,
      business_units.unit_name,
      business_unit_types.unit_type_name,
      business_unit_categories.unit_category_name
      from
      sections,
      countries,
      cities,
      business_units,
      business_unit_types,
      business_unit_categories 
      where 
           business_units.section_id=sections.section_id
      and  business_units.country_id=countries.country_id
      and  business_units.city_id=cities.city_id
      and  business_units.unit_type_id=business_unit_types.unit_type_id
      and  business_units.unit_category_id=business_unit_categories.unit_category_id
      and  cities.country_id=countries.country_id;
```

**transaction_details**

```
          SELECT
      transactions.business_date,
      transactions.transaction_datetime,
      business_unit_product_category_section.section_id,
      business_units.country_id,
      transactions.unit_id,
      transactions.transaction_id,
      product_category_groups.product_category_group_name,
      transactions.product_category_id,
      product_categories.product_category_name,
      transactions.product_id,
      products.product_name,
      transactions.net_sales
      FROM 
      transactions,
      business_unit_product_category_section,
      business_units,
      products,
      product_categories,
      product_category_groups 
      where 
          transactions.unit_id=business_unit_product_category_section.unit_id
      and transactions.product_category_id=business_unit_product_category_section.product_category_id
      and transactions.unit_id=business_units.unit_id 
      and business_unit_product_category_section.section_id=business_units.section_id 
      and business_unit_product_category_section.unit_id=business_units.unit_id
      and transactions.product_id=products.product_id 
      and transactions.product_category_id=products.product_category_id
      and transactions.product_category_id=product_categories.product_category_id
      and product_categories.product_category_id=products.product_category_id
      and product_categories.product_category_group_id=product_category_groups.product_category_group_id;
```

**final view**

```
          select 
      unit_details.section_name,
      unit_details.country_name,
      unit_details.city_name,
      unit_details.unit_name,
      unit_details.unit_type_name,
      unit_details.unit_category_name,
      transaction_details.business_date,
      transaction_details.transaction_datetime,
      transaction_details.section_id,
      transaction_details.country_id,
      transaction_details.unit_id,
      transaction_details.transaction_id,
      transaction_details.product_category_group_name,
      transaction_details.product_category_id,
      transaction_details.product_category_name,
      transaction_details.product_id,
      transaction_details.product_name,
      transaction_details.net_sales
      from unit_details ud
      left join transaction_details td on 
      td.section_id=ud.section_id
      and 
      td.country_id=ud.country_id
      and 
      td.unit_id=ud.unit_id;
```

this is one of my summary table query
the summary tables updated every 30 minutes by a batch file executing the SQL.

```
          SET @date_today = DATE(NOW());
      select
      final_view.section_name,
      final_view.country_name,
      final_view.city_name,
      final_view.unit_name,
      final_view.unit_type_name,
      final_view.unit_category_name,
      sum(CASE WHEN @date_today = final_view.business_date THEN final_view.net_sales ELSE 0 END) TODAYS_NETSALES,
      sum(CASE WHEN month(@date_today) = month(final_view.business_date) and final_view.business_date<=@date_today THEN final_view.net_sales ELSE 0 END) MTD_NETSALES
      from final_view
      group by final_view.section_name,final_view.country_name,final_view.city_name,final_view.unit_name,final_view.unit_category_name;
```

this is my schema

```
          CREATE TABLE business_units (
        id int(11) NOT NULL,
        unit_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        unit_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        section_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        country_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        city_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        unit_type_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        unit_category_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        created_by varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_datetime datetime NOT NULL,
        is_active_status int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-active, 0-not active',
        status_change_datetime datetime NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

      CREATE TABLE business_unit_categories (
        unit_category_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        unit_category_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_by varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_datetime datetime NOT NULL,
        is_active_status int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-active, 0-not active',
        status_change_datetime datetime NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

      CREATE TABLE business_unit_product_category_section (
        id int(11) NOT NULL,
        unit_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        product_category_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        section_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        created_by varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_datetime datetime NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

      CREATE TABLE business_unit_types (
        unit_type_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        unit_type_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_by varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_datetime datetime NOT NULL,
        is_active_status int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-active, 0-not active',
        status_change_datetime datetime NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


      CREATE TABLE cities (
        city_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        city_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        country_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        created_by varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_datetime datetime NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


      CREATE TABLE countries (
        country_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        country_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_by varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_datetime datetime NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


      CREATE TABLE products (
        id int(11) NOT NULL,
        product_id varchar(13) NOT NULL,
        product_name varchar(300) NOT NULL,
        product_category_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        created_by varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_datetime datetime NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


      CREATE TABLE product_categories (
        product_category_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        product_category_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        product_category_group_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        created_by varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_datetime datetime NOT NULL,
        is_active_status int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-active, 0-not active',
        status_change_datetime datetime NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


      CREATE TABLE product_category_groups (
        product_category_group_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        product_category_group_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_by varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_datetime datetime NOT NULL,
        is_active_status int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-active, 0-not active',
        status_change_datetime datetime NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

      CREATE TABLE sections (
        section_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        section_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_by varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        created_datetime datetime NOT NULL,
        is_active_status int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-active, 0-not active',
        status_change_datetime datetime NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


      CREATE TABLE transactions (
        id int(11) NOT NULL,
        business_date date NOT NULL,
        unit_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        transaction_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        transaction_datetime datetime NOT NULL,
        product_category_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        product_id varchar(13) NOT NULL,
        net_sales float NOT NULL,
        net_qty int(11) NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

      CREATE TABLE user_permissions (
      id int(11) NOT NULL,
      user_id varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      section_id int(11) NOT NULL,
      country_id int(11) NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


      ALTER TABLE business_units
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
        ADD UNIQUE KEY unit_id (unit_id,section_id,country_id),
        ADD KEY unit_id_2 (unit_id,section_id,country_id),
        ADD KEY city_id (city_id),
        ADD KEY unit_type_id (unit_type_id),
        ADD KEY unit_category_id (unit_category_id);


      ALTER TABLE business_unit_categories
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (unit_category_id);


      ALTER TABLE business_unit_product_category_section
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
        ADD UNIQUE KEY unit_id (unit_id,product_category_id,section_id),
        ADD KEY unit_id_2 (unit_id,product_category_id,section_id);


      ALTER TABLE business_unit_types
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (unit_type_id);


      ALTER TABLE cities
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (city_id),
        ADD UNIQUE KEY city_id (city_id,country_id),
        ADD KEY country_id (country_id),
        ADD KEY city_id_2 (city_id,country_id);


      ALTER TABLE countries
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (country_id);


      ALTER TABLE products
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
        ADD KEY product_id (product_id),
        ADD KEY product_category_id (product_category_id);


      ALTER TABLE product_categories
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (product_category_id),
        ADD UNIQUE KEY product_category_id (product_category_id,product_category_group_id),
        ADD KEY product_category_group_id (product_category_group_id);


      ALTER TABLE product_category_groups
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (product_category_group_id);


      ALTER TABLE sections
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (section_id);


      ALTER TABLE transactions
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
        ADD KEY business_date (business_date),
        ADD KEY unit_id (unit_id),
        ADD KEY transaction_id (transaction_id),
        ADD KEY transaction_datetime (transaction_datetime),
        ADD KEY product_category_id (product_category_id),
        ADD KEY product_id (product_id),
        ADD KEY product_id_3 (product_id,product_category_id);


      ALTER TABLE transactions
        MODIFY id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

      ALTER TABLE user_permissions
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
      ADD UNIQUE KEY user_id_3 (user_id,section_id,country_id),
      ADD KEY user_id (user_id),
      ADD KEY section_id (section_id),
      ADD KEY country_id (country_id),
      ADD KEY user_id_2 (user_id,section_id,country_id);

      ALTER TABLE user_permissions
      MODIFY id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

my question is,

whether it is advisable to create predefined views like the above and do selects from predefined view and inserting into summary tables?

or should i remove the predefined views and summary tables and stop the batch and generate the summary view through PHP page only when users accessing the dashboard during the session?

the reason why i have created the predefined views is, the transactions table got millions of record and it takes around 10 to 15 minutes to update the summary tables. and when the user access the dashboard the data is available and user need not wait to see the data.

if i generate the data during the session user will have to wait 10 to 15 minutes to see the data.

kindly advice on proper approach and also on help me to optimize the sql query.

Comment: We stopped writing queries this way ca. 1992. Come. JOIN us.

Comment: TL;DR please provide a SHORT reproducible problem

Comment: @DanFromGermany, the problem is , the query takes so much time to give the results if i execute the query during the session, so currently I’m generating the results every 30 minuets and keeping the output ready for the user when they login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Unclutter - I agree with Strawberry's textual changes.
- Unclutter - Don't normalize Country, just include it in City.
- Unclutter - Do you really need `created_by` and `created_datetime`.
- Unclutter - Don't use 5-word table names.
- Use `JOIN ... ON ...` instead of the old "comma join".
- Don't have both `INDEX(a)` and `INDEX(a,b)`; the former is redundant and unnecessary.
- A `UNIQUE` index is an index, so `INDEX(a,b)` is unnecessary when you also have `UNIQUE(a,b)`.

Back to some of your question...

- A `VIEW` (in MySQL) is syntactic sugar -- it can never be faster than the equivalent `SELECT`.  (Though it may be easier to read.)
- There is no explicit support for Summary Tables in MySQL (even with `VIEWs`).  However manually implementing such is a good idea for performance; I sometimes see *10-times* performance improvement.

Comment: thank u. the index related doubts are cleared now, thank you so much. so i will be using summary tables as it is, the only change i have to do is, instead of selecting from views and inserting into summary table, directly select from tables and insert into summary tables ?

Comment: @davidb - That's a brief summary of summary table use ;) .  More on Summary Tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: thank you, this was a great insight on summary tables. it clears my doubts.

Comment: ,could you please advice on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47976837/mysql-optimization-suggestion-for-large-table

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment.

We would normally write these sorts of queries this way. I suggest you start here and amend your question (and possibly your data model) accordingly...

```
SELECT s.section_id
     , c.country_id
     , u.unit_id
     , s.section_name
     , c.country_name
     , x.city_name
     , u.unit_name
     , t.unit_type_name
     , y.unit_category_name
  FROM sections s
  JOIN business_units u
    ON u.section_id = s.section_id
  JOIN countries c
    ON u.country_id = c.country_id
  JOIN cities x
    ON x.city_id = u.city_id 
   AND x.country_id = c.country_id -- there is a redundancy in your model here
  JOIN business_unit_types t
    ON t.unit_type_id = u.unit_type_id 
  JOIN business_unit_categories y
    ON y.unit_category_id u.unit_category_id
```

Comment: thank you, could you please advise whether it is good to have a predefined views ? or else is there any other good approach which will give faster results?

Comment: I can’t comment on other RDBMSs. In MySQL, there’s very limited opportunity for queries against views to use indexes, so in my opinion there’s very little merit in using views.

Comment: After using JOINS, use `EXPLAIN` before the query so it will show you how many rows it has to examine and if it uses a key. Then you can change the order of your JOINs and maybe add `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to speed up things. Also check if your scheme is fully normalized and if you don't pull data you don't need. That way you can query a large number of results in milliseconds.

Comment: @DanFromGermany All good advice. Probably best directed towards the OP.