# Mysql Optimization suggestion for large table

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to optimize this query,

```
select  location_id, dept_id,
        round(sum(sales),0), sum(qty),
        count(distinct tran_id),
        now()
    from  tran_sales
    where  tran_date <= '2016-12-24'
    group by  location_id, dept_id;
```

currently this query runs for around average of 98 seconds  (Query took 97.4096 seconds.)
in windows 10, 64 Bit OS, 16 GB RAM.

this is the table detail for your reference.

```
    CREATE TABLE tran_sales (
    tran_date date NOT NULL,
    location_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    dept_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    item_id varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    tran_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    sales float DEFAULT NULL,
    qty int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    update_datetime datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (tran_date,location_id,dept_id,item_id,tran_id),
    KEY tran_date (tran_date)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

the record count in table tran_sales: **13.5 Million**.

**Note:** Even i tried without and with this index `KEY tran_date (tran_date)` . and average time it takes is 98 seconds with and without `KEY tran_date (tran_date)`

please suggest how to speedup the results by either changing the query or by changing some default settings of my.ini if that helps. Thanks.

**Update**
the min date in table is : 2016-07-01,  and the max date in table is : 2017-07-25

Comment: Why do you have `now()` in group by claude ? `Now()` function may cause your `group by` means nothing because It seems doesn't group anything

Comment: @KhánhBùiĐức, that was a typo error, i have edited it.

Comment: Can you remove tran_date from primary key ? If not change position of your primary key as `(location_id,dept_id, tran_date,item_id,tran_id)`. Your where clause takes advance of key tran_date, but primary key doesn't help group by clause

Comment: @KhánhBùiĐức, thanks, the query uses primary key when i checked in explain. i will change the tran_date position and check if the query uses tran_date key. will let you know the result shortly. thanks.

Comment: @KhánhBùiĐức, i have changed the position of primary key like you said. but it didnt help. when i used `where tran_date='2016-12-24'` in explain i can see the key `tran_date` is used. but when i used  `where tran_date<='2016-12-24'` the key is null in explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the suggestions so far will help much, because...

- Covering index: That is only slightly smaller than the table, so it is slightly faster.
- `KEY(tran_date)` -- a waste; it is better to use the PK, which starts with `tran_date`.
- `PARTITIONing` -- No.  That is likely to be slower.
- Removing `tran_date` (or otherwise rearranging the PK) -- This will hurt.  The filtering (`WHERE`) is on `tran_date`; it is usually best to have that *first*.
- So, why was `COUNT(*)` fast?  Well, start by looking at the `EXPLAIN`.  It will show that it used `KEY(tran_date)` *instead* of scanning the table.  Less data to scan, hence faster.

The real issue is that you have millions of rows to scan, *it takes time to touch millions of rows*.

How to speed it up?  Create and maintain a [*Summary table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) .  Then query that table (with thousands of rows) instead of the original table (millions of rows).  Total count is `SUM(counts)`; total sum is `SUM(sums)`; average is `SUM(sums)/SUM(counts)`, etc.

Comment: thank you for the tips, i will create and maintain summary tables.

Comment: please suggest, as i have the PRIMARY KEY like this already (tran_date,location_id,dept_id,item_id,tran_id), i still need an additional covering index KEY (tran_date,location_id,dept_id,item_id,tran_id) ?

Comment: @davidb - definitely do not add a redundant index.  Let's see the typical `SELECTs`, only then can I advise on the `PRIMARY KEY` and other indexes.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
select location_id, dept_id,
       round(sum(sales), 0), sum(qty), count(distinct tran_id),
       now()
from tran_sales
where tran_date <= '2016-12-24'
group by location_id, dept_id;
```

There is not much you can do.  One attempt would be a covering index:  `(tran_date, location_id, dept_id, sales, qty)`, but I don't think that will help much.

Comment: thank you, i will apply this covering index `(tran_date, location_id, dept_id, sales, qty)` and try now.

Comment: after adding covering index like this (tran_date, location_id, dept_id, sales, qty) i got result in 82 seconds. does partitioning help ?

Comment: @davidb . . . Partitioning might help a bit, but probably not much.  Aggregation queries are hard to optimize in MySQL.  Can you use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT)`?

Comment: when i tried `count(*)` the query took less than 3 seconds. the transactions count for each department in location will be different in count(*). could you please advice if any possibility to use `count (*)` to match the result as per `count (distinct)`

Comment: @davidb . . . That depends on the nature of the data.  Only you can answer that.

Comment: just an update,i have created range partitions now with month wise, even then the query is slow only. query takes same time as before.